# How to make auto numbering on UITextview when press return key in swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, swift3, autonumber, sequential-number

When user press [Return] key then  need to display the number. Like serial numbers [1,2 etc] for each line.Is there any way to do that?

Following code I tried

```
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    var textview_text_nssring = textView.text as NSString




    // Add "1" when the user starts typing into the text field


    if  (range.location == 0 && textView.text.isEmpty ) {


        if text == "\n" {

            textView.text = "1."

            let cursor = NSMakeRange(range.location + 3, 0)
            textView.selectedRange = cursor
            return false
        }

        else {

            textView.text = NSString(format: "1. %@", text) as String
        }


    }




 return true

}
```

Comment: Show us what you have try.

Comment: @NiravD updated.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare one `Int` var for current line number and use it inside `shouldChangeTextIn range` like this way.

```
var currentLine: Int = 1 

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // Add "1" when the user starts typing into the text field
    if  (textView.text.isEmpty && !text.isEmpty) {
        textView.text = "\(currentLine). "
        currentLine += 1
    }
    else {
        if text.isEmpty {
            if textView.text.characters.count >= 4 {
                let str = textView.text.substring(from:textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -4))
                if str.hasPrefix("\n") {
                    textView.text = String(textView.text.characters.dropLast(3))
                    currentLine -= 1
                }
            }
            else if text.isEmpty && textView.text.characters.count == 3 {
                textView.text = String(textView.text.characters.dropLast(3))
                currentLine = 1
            }
        }
        else {
            let str = textView.text.substring(from:textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -1))
            if str == "\n" {
                textView.text = "\(textView.text!)\(currentLine). "
                currentLine += 1
            }
        }

    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But this code does not handle backspace.If we hit backspace even increase number

Comment: @Lydia Check the edited answer for reduce line number when removed.

Comment: Worked perfect.It also handle the editing of previous text

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: I have used the above code but it's not working for me in Swift 5 just got the first (1. text) after increment not working

Comment: Thank you man. You saved my time. Entire google search other results useless in front of your answer even gpt 4.